# Super simple question about about command line '$ node example.js'

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, command, node.js

So I'm working on my first node.js 'Hello World' on a linux machine and I successfully got everything going by running

```
$ node example.js
```

I went to the browser and everything worked fine.  Going back to the command line, I see the msg "Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8080" as indicated from the example.js.  The only thing is that I can't return to regular command line prompt so I can do more work.  It's giving me blank lines where I can type whatever I want with no discernible results.  I don't know enough about linux commands to get out of whatever mode I'm in.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ctrl-C is used to break command on Unix(Linux)